# How do i rotate around the center of the text geometry in react-three-fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I'm currently working on a little side project, where i am using react-three-fiber.
I have the following code which renders a text geometry with the display "Test".
For some reason the Text Geometry gets rotated at the bottom left corner instead of it being rotated around its own center.
How can i change the behavior so that it rotates around its own center?

```
export function TextMesh(props){
    const textMesh = useRef();
    const font = new FontLoader().parse(props.font);

    useHelper(textMesh, BoxHelper, 'cyan');

    useEffect( () => {
    })

    useFrame( ({clock}) => {
        textMesh.current.rotation.y = clock.getElapsedTime(); 
    })
    
    return (
        <mesh ref={textMesh} position={[-1,-0.25,0]}>
            <textGeometry args={["Test", {
                font: font, 
                size: .5,
                height: 0.1
            }]}/>
            <meshStandardMaterial/>
        </mesh>
    );
}
```

Here the Code where i wrap the TextMesh onto the Canvas

```
export default function App() {
  //... Other code
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          //... Other code
          <TextMesh font={Roboto}/>
          <OrbitControls />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently it looks like this[image]

Any help is appreciated!

---

I solved it adding following code to the useEffect Hook.

```
useEffect( () => {
        textMesh.current.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        const boundingBox = textMesh.current.geometry.boundingBox;
        const center = new THREE.Vector3();
        boundingBox.getCenter(center);
        textMesh.current.geometry.translate(-center.x,-center.y,-center.z);            
})`
```

Comment: Your own solution is perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Text geometry's rotation origin is in the left side. You could change this origin as a [one-time operation with `geometry.translate(x, y, z)`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate).

I don't know how wide your text is, but you'll probably want to translate it half of its width in the x-axis so the origin lands in the middle:

```
// Translate the geometry
textMesh.current.geometry.translate(1, 0, 0);

// Return to its starting position
textMesh.current.position.set(-1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. I fixed it by adding code to the useEffect Hook. Why exactly are you first doing a translate then a set? I solved it by translating it to the half of its enclosing boxes width as you proposed, so thanks for the idea!